# multiple Inheritance .. class need to extend abstractHandler as well as Applet

Tags: eclipse-plugin, applet, command, multiple-inheritance, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to make an automation wizard that would take some files from system (via a command handler) and make its relevant applet.

I shall try to explain my senario.

I made a plugin for new command "newModule" which is handled via "newModuleHandler.java". so **newModuleHandler extends AbstractHandler**.

Now i would like to make a wizard (applet) that helps me with certain selections that i need to make in order to complete that "newModule" command. so 
**newModuleHandler extends Applet** too.

i wrote newModuleHandler something like this.

```
    package archetypedcomponent.commands;

    import org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler;
    import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionEvent;
    import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException;
    import java.applet.*;// required when you create an applet 
    import java.awt.Graphics;


    public class newModuleHandler extends AbstractHandler {

    @Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isHandled() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return null;
}

public class HelloWorld extends Applet 
{
    // The method that will be automatically called  when the applet is started 
     public void init() 
     { 
         // It is required but does not need anything. 
         System.out.println("Applet initiated");
     } 


    // This method gets called when the applet is terminated 
    // That's when the user goes to another page or exits the browser. 
     public void stop() 
     { 
         //     no actions needed here now.
         System.out.println("Applet Stopped");
     } 


    // The standard method that you have to use to paint things on screen 
    // This overrides the empty Applet method, you can't called it "display" for example.

     public void paint(Graphics g) 
     { 
         //method to draw text on screen 
         // String first, then x and y coordinate. 
         System.out.println("Applet in paint");
          g.drawString("Hey hey hey",20,20); 
          g.drawString("Hellooow World",20,40);

     }
}
```

}

Now when the command will b given this method will be called

```
@Override
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return null;
}
```

and applet will have to be called inside it. **my question is how to call it?**

========================================================================================
i was able to solve my problem but m replying here so that somebody who is also facing same problem can b guided

this is my new **"newModuleHandler.java"**

```
    package archetypedcomponent.commands;

    import org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler;
   import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionEvent;
  import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException;
    import java.applet.*;// required when you create an applet 
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class newModuleHandler extends AbstractHandler {

    @Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isHandled() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//  call applet here
     JFrame jp1 = new JFrame();
        Loader a=new Loader ();
        jp1.getContentPane().add(a, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jp1.setSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        jp1.setVisible(true);

    return null;
}
```

}

i made a new **Loader.java** which extends applet

```
    package archetypedcomponent.commands;

    import java.applet.Applet;
    import java.awt.Graphics;

    public class Loader extends Applet 
    {
// The method that will be automatically called  when the applet is started 
 public void init() 
 { 
     // It is required but does not need anything. 
     System.out.println("Applet initiated");
//   Graphics g=new ;

 } 


// This method gets called when the applet is terminated 
// That's when the user goes to another page or exits the browser. 
 public void stop() 
 { 
     //     no actions needed here now.
     System.out.println("Applet Stopped");
 } 


// The standard method that you have to use to paint things on screen 
// This overrides the empty Applet method, you can't called it "display" for example.

 public void paint(Graphics g) 
 { 
     //method to draw text on screen 
     // String first, then x and y coordinate. 
     System.out.println("Applet in paint");
      g.drawString("Hey hey hey",20,20); 
      g.drawString("Hellooow World",20,40);

 }
```

}

Now whatever i need applet to do can b done in paint of Loader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An applet can have more than one Object, so `extends AbstractHandler` in some other class that the applet has a reference to.

Comment: [Delegation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) may be an appropriate pattern in this case.

Comment: thanx... now i m having a different kind of problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965655/1-repaint-of-applet-is-called-after-the-jframe-window-is-moved-2-not-all-co